# Code suggestion for nested grouping ActiveRecord | Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by, rails-activerecord

I'm working on a project that needs to do some basic statistic reporting. For example, the model `Post` has a foreign key field `category_id` referring to a record in the `Category` model, and boolean field `published` which has a default value of `false` (along with `title`, `body`, `author` - but they're not relevant to this question).

I want to set up and nested grouping to iterate through the `Post` model and group the `Post` records by their `Category`, and then within each category, further group by the state of the `published` field, to give a `count` for each grouping, to render an outcome similar to below:

```
Categories
Tutorial
  Published: 14 posts
  Draft:     3 posts
Q & A
  Published: 14 posts
  Draft:     3 posts
Letter
  Published: 14 posts
  Draft:     3 posts
```

Below is the non-functional code I've started with:

```html
<% @posts.group(:category).each do |category| %>
  <% category.label %>

  <% category.each.group(:published).count.each do |published_status, count| %>
    <%= published_status %>: <%= pluralize(count, "post") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any feedback or suggestions on how to modify the code above would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `Tutorial, Q & A, Letter`  are name of category . right ?

Comment: That's right, yeah (`category.label`)

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query it is not tested but i think it should work

**NOT TESTED**

```
categories = Category.left_outer_joins(:posts)
                                .select("
                                       Categories.label, 
                                       (SELECT COUNT(posts.id) from posts where posts.published=true) as published_count, 
                                       (SELECT COUNT(posts.id) from posts where posts.published=false) as draft_count
                                       ")
                                .group('categories.id')
```

In View

```
<% categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.label %>
  <%= category.published_count %>
  <%= category.draft_count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I seem to be getting the syntax error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM posts WHERE posts.published=true) AS published_count, ' at line 3: SELECT`. Let me know what you think. Thanks again.

Comment: @slehmann36 Ohh I thought you used postgres for your application. I am not much aware about mysql. Can you please check my updated answer?